# How to combine rows using a CASE Statement

Tags: sqlite

I have a database with 58 customers(58 rows) with a column(country). How do I group up all the rows where a country only appears once and change its name to "Other" using a `CASE` Statement

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(country) FROM customer GROUP BY country)=1 THEN 'Other'
        ELSE country
    END country
FROM customer
```

The problem is that when I run my query, all the countries become Other. I only want the countries that appear once to be called Other.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it.

```sql
SELECT
CASE WHEN COUNT(country) = 1 THEN 'Other' ELSE country END
FROM customer
GROUP BY country;
```

Answer (score 0):

With a subquery that counts how many times a country appears in the table:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer WHERE country = c.country) = 1 THEN 'Other' 
    ELSE c.country 
  END country 
FROM customer c
```

Or with a join of the table to the subquery that returns all the counter of all the countries:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN g.counter = 1 THEN 'Other' 
    ELSE c.country 
  END country 
FROM customer c INNER JOIN (
  SELECT country, COUNT(*) counter 
  FROM customer 
  GROUP BY country
) g ON g.country = c.country
```

If you want your table grouped by the result of this CASE statement use an alias to distinguish from the table's column `country`:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer WHERE country = c.country) = 1 THEN 'Other' 
    ELSE c.country 
  END _country 
FROM customer c
GROUP BY _country
```

Comment: Thanks! the solution you wrote works but I dont understand how the WHERE statement country=c.country works. Could you explain that? Thanks

Comment: `c` is the alias of the main table `customer`. The subquery: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer WHERE country = c.country` returns the number of rows for each `c.country`.

Answer (score 0):

To update the actual table:

```
WITH map AS
  (SELECT country, 
          CASE WHEN COUNT(country) = 1 THEN 'Other'
               ELSE country END mapped
   FROM customer
   GROUP BY country) 
UPDATE customer
SET country = (SELECT mapped FROM map WHERE map.country = customer.country);
```